# Child and parent class property

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with a name `Parent` and a class `Child` that inherits `Parent` class.`Parent` class has a property `filename` with value `testfile`.In the first step I change the value of this property for example on `anothertestvalue` in `Parent` class `testFileame` method.Then I try to  call method `log` from `Child` class and this method try to get `filename` property from `Parent` class.

```
class Parent {
     public $filename = 'filename';

     public function  setFilename() {
          $this->filename = 'anotherfilename'
     }

     public function log($message, $this->filename) {
          //here filename from Child class has value 'filename' but I expect 'anotherfilename'
     }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    $this->log("somemessage");
}
```

I expect to get `anothertestvalue` value but method uses `testfile`.Can someone explain what happens?

Comment: Show us some code and we'll be able to help. Descriptions like this are useless without a code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the notion of CLASS and INSTANCE.
You should have an instance of your Child class which calls setFilename.

```
class MyParent {
    private $filename = 'filename';

    public function setFilename($name) {
        $this->filename = $name;
    }

    public function log($message) {
        //here filename from Child class has value 'filename' but I expect 'anotherfilename'
        print $this->filename;
    }
 }

 class MyChild extends MyParent {
    //...
 }

 $child = new MyChild();
 $child->setFilename("anotherfilename");
 $child->log("somemessage"); // print "anotherfilename"
```

Further details here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not setting the value. You just defined a method, that will set the value **if** called.

So in short, call the method `setFilename()` and then the value will change.

Comment: But I thought changing property value in parent class would be enough to use in child class. And `setFilename` method called before calling `log` method from child.