# get child class name without passing value through the argument

Tags: php, oop

This question is difficult to ask, as it seems to answer.

I have a method declared in abstract class `parent{}`, that gets echoed in child class `foo{}`

This method requires the current current class name i.e. `foo` to work, So how do I get this name without passing it through the argumet?

#### EXAMPLE

```
abstract class parent{
  public function init(){
     echo "I am running from class ...."; 
  // I want this to say, that is it running from any class that is extending it. 
  } 
}
```

This is the child class, and is only supposed to hold one username;

```
class foo extends parent{
   echo $this->init(); 
 // I could pass the class name through the argument, but I am looking for other alternatives  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sroes has the answer, but your code example could be something like:

```
abstract class parentclass{
  public function init(){
     echo "I am running from class ...."; 
        echo __CLASS__;    

        echo ' But I am ' . get_class($this);         
  } 
}

class foo extends parentclass{
}

$f = new foo();
$f->init();
```

Shows diff between const **CLASS** and get_class()

Comment: I know. I tried `__CLASS__` but `get_class()` seemed to do it. I just don't understand how both are getting those class names differently.

Comment: "Diff between CLASS and INSTANCE" says http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132230/child-and-parent-class-property?rq=1

Comment: Seems like sroes has disappeared, even though he made gave the answer, you explained the problem txs

Comment: Well tbh, @sroes came up with the correct answer as I was trying to work it out, I was only illustrating.

Answer (score 5):

```
 echo "I am running from class " . get_class($this);
```

`__CLASS__` is the declaring class (the class you're using it in) and `get_class` will get the concrete class of the provided object. So `get_class($this)` will return the same value as `__CLASS__` or one of its child classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just out of curiosity, WHY didn't `__CLASS__` work?